# Method doesn't start on Android?

Tags: java, android, methods

My custom audio application starts to play when the Main activity begins, but I'd like it to start playing when the user hits the "Play" button. Just for the record I'm not using the Android `MediaPlayer`, but my own player.

When I simply use `startPlayer()` it runs fine, when the Activity starts, but when I put the `startPlayer()` invokation inside the `setOnClickListener()` it doesn't work.

The method `startPlayer()` in being called (it's logging fine), but the audio player doesn't fire up. Why?

Here is the code:

```
play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.playbutton);
        play.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {                               
                startPlayer();

            }
        });


    }

    private void startPlayer() {
        try {
            player.playAudio();     

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            finish();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is `player.playAudio()` being executed? Otherwise you should log the exception and figure out what error the code is throwing.

Answer (score 0):

```
    play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {                               
            startPlayer();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Sardor, but it didn't work either. I'm suspecting it's a thread issue.